# Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, sikuli-script

I use Eclipse IDE, selenium-java v4.8.3, and after I added the SikuliX API version 2.0.5 in my dependencies, I encountered this error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: >Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the >remote server or browser start-up failure.

I already checked the compatibility of my edge browser and edge webdriver, also the file path of my ***msedgedriver.exe***. I also tried to use ChromeDriver, and restart my PC. However, I still have this error.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;



public class HandlingUploadDownloadFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "D:\\Programming-Tools\\Eclipse IDE\\WebDriver\\Edge\\edgedriver_win64\\msedgedriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(); // Instantiate driver object
        driver.get("https://www.ilovepdf.com/pdf_to_word"); // Open link
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); // Maximize window
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='pickfiles']")).click();
        
        String filePath = "D:\\Projects\\Test Automation\\AutomationPractice\\AutomationPractice\\files\\";
        
        Screen screen = new Screen();
        
        Pattern inputTextField = new Pattern(filePath+"InputTextField.png");
        Pattern openButton = new Pattern(filePath+"OpenButton.png");
        
        screen.wait(inputTextField, 10);
        screen.type(inputTextField, filePath+"SampleFile.pdf");
        screen.click(openButton);
        
        
        
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code by just changing the version of sikuli to below, and it worked fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```